# Are there any problems with this design?

Tags: robotic-arm

https://www.reddit.com/r/robotics/comments/nbqx55/does_this_design_for_a_leg_make_sense_description/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

So essentially I'm trying to make a leg that's able to kick. Motor A drives a pole, and that pole is connected to another pole with a hinge. That second pole can either be extended or retracted like a calf, it can do this by a string that's connected to the end of it that goes through the first pole, into the shaft of motor A, out the center of the shaft, and into Motor B that retracts or let's go of the line in order to control whether the calf is extended or not, determined by code.

Comment: it is your job to determine the problems and then ask for help here ... this is a Q&A site ... not a forum ... not a brainstorming site

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Bob reee, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: @jsotola - If you think it shouldn't be on the site (it shouldn't) then please vote to close the question.